# How to send data periodically with asyncio.Protocol subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have `asyncio.Protocol` subclass

```
class MyProtocol(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, exit_future):
        self.exit_future = exit_future

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        pass

    def eof_received(self):
        self.exit_future.set_result(True)

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        self.exit_future.set_result(True)
```

and network connection created with

```
while True:
    try:
        exit_future = Future(loop=loop)
        transport, protocol = await loop.create_connection(lambda: MyProtocol(exit_future), host, port)

        await exit_future
        transport.close()
    except:
        pass
```

Now the question is: how can I send some data on some external event occurs? For instance when `asyncio.Queue` is not empty (`queue.get` will not block), what fills that queue is not related to asyncio? What is the most correct way to call `transport.write` when something happens?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I send some data on some external event occurs?

The easiest way is to spawn the coroutine in `connection_made` and leave it to handle the event in the "background":

```
def connection_made(self, transport):
    self.transport = transport
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    self._interesting_events = asyncio.Queue()
    self.monitor = loop.create_task(self._monitor_impl())

def connection_lost(self, exc):
    self.exit_future.set_result(True)
    self.monitor.cancel()

async def _monitor_impl(self):
    while True:
        # this can also await asyncio.sleep() or whatever is needed
        event = await self._interesting_events.get()
        self.transport.write(...)
```

Note that in the long run it might be worth it to replace `create_connection` with [`open_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.open_connection) and use the streams API from the ground up. That way you can use coroutines all the way without worrying about the callback/coroutine impedance mismatch.

On an unrelated note, `try` followed by `except: pass` is an [anti-pattern](https://realpython.com/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/) - consider catching a specific exception instead, or at least logging the exception.